# PHP Invite Code Redirector

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making a website and want to implement an Invite Program. I want to make it so if the user goes to https://example.com/invite/code, it redirects to https://example.com/?rc=code. Below is my current htaccess, and I cannot have the new code interfere. Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original url doesn't contain a query string which you want to keep:

```
RewriteRule ^invite/(.*)$  "/?rc=$1" [PT]
```